# Python: for each tuple in list, check if string in tuple

Tags: python, list, tuples

I know how to cycle through all tuples in a list. However, my problem is to see if a string is in a tuple within the list. I have constructed the following:

```
# where:
unformatted_returns = [('2015-6-10', u'88.48'), ('2015-6-9', u'86.73'), ('2015-6-8', u'86.15'), ('2015-6-5', u'86.05')]
date_new  = '2015-6-8'

for n in unformatted_returns: # The problem is here
    if str(date_new) in n[0]: 
        print "found date"
        rate_of_return_calc(date, date_new)
        pass
    else:
        print "date {0} not found".format(date_new)
        day_accumulater(d, m, y, date_new, date)
```

The problem is that the first tuple in the cycle `n in unformatted_returns` does not satisfy the condition, therefore it prints "not found". I don't want it do this obviously, because `date_new` is actually in the list!

So, how do I get the program to cycle through each `n`, then if all `n`'s do not satisfy containing `date_new` then print `"day not found"`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move the `else` *one level down*. `for` loops also take an `else` suite, which is executed when you *did not exit the loop early*. Then add a `break`:

```
for n in unformatted_returns:
    if date_new == n[0]: 
        print "found date"
        rate_of_return_calc(date, date_new)
        break
else:
    print "date {0} not found".format(date_new)
    day_accumulater(d, m, y, date_new, date)
```

I've also cleaned up your test; you are matching `n[0]` against a date string, you want them to be *equal*, not for one to be a substring of the other.

Now one of two things can happen:

- `date_new` is equal to the first element of one of the tuples. The `break` is executed, the `for` loop ends, and the `else` suite is skipped.
- `date_new` is not equal to any of the first elements of the tuples. The `break` is never executed, the loop ends and the `else` suite is executed to show no match was found.

Demo:

```
>>> unformatted_returns = [('2015-6-10', u'88.48'), ('2015-6-9', u'86.73'), ('2015-6-8', u'86.15'), ('2015-6-5', u'86.05')]
>>> date_new  = '2015-6-8'
>>> for n in unformatted_returns:
...     if date_new == n[0]: 
...         print "found date"
...         break
... else:
...     print "date {0} not found".format(date_new)
... 
found date
>>> date_new = '2015-6-7'  # not in the list
>>> for n in unformatted_returns:
...     if date_new == n[0]: 
...         print "found date"
...         break
... else:
...     print "date {0} not found".format(date_new)
... 
date 2015-6-7 not found
```

This obviously would only ever find the *first* such matching element.

If you must process all matching elements, a flag is usually easiest:

```
found = False

for n in unformatted_returns:
    if date_new == n[0]: 
        print "found date"
        rate_of_return_calc(date, date_new)
        found = True

if not found:
    print "date {0} not found".format(date_new)
    day_accumulater(d, m, y, date_new, date)
```

All this assumes that `n[1]` is of interest too. If all you need to know if the date is *present*, use `any()` and a generator expression to test for *a* matching element:

```
if any(n[0] == date_new for n in unformatted_returns):
    print "found date"
    rate_of_return_calc(date, date_new)
else:
    print "date {0} not found".format(date_new)
    day_accumulater(d, m, y, date_new, date)
```

Now we won't know *which* `n` matched, but that doesn't actually matter.

Comment: Awesome! There won't ever be more then 1 matching element as the list is cleansed of duplicates prior to this function. But thanks for the info anyhow!

Answer (score 1):

Just use a flag:

```
unformatted_returns = [('2015-6-10', u'88.48'), ('2015-6-9', u'86.73'), ('2015-6-8', u'86.15'), ('2015-6-5', u'86.05')]
date_new  = '2015-6-8'
found_one = False

for n in unformatted_returns: # The problem is here
    if str(date_new) in n[0]: 
        print "found date"
        rate_of_return_calc(date, date_new)
        found_one = True
        # add a break here if you are only interested in the first match
if not found_one:
    print "date {0} not found".format(date_new)
    day_accumulater(d, m, y, date_new, date)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just search for matches and if the search comes with no results, nothing was found:

```
matching_returns = [ur for ur in unformatted_returns if date_new == ur[0]]
if not matching_returns:
    print "date {0} not found".format(date_new)
else:
    # do something with matching_returns
```